# High Sierra file sharing on Macs not working for Active Directory users

Tags: macos, mac, high-sierra, file-sharing, active-directory

Running Macs, High Sierra, in a lab environment.  Serving K-12 students.  File sharing important as students drop off assignments (files) to instructor computer.  However, students logged on to the Active Directory domain cannot drop off files in the instructor's public folder-->Drop Box.  SMB and AFS sharing both enabled in System Prefs (sharing).  Testing with local accounts on same computers, file sharing works (local account can drop off files) but AD user accounts cannot.

Any ideas?

Comment: Active Directory is a Windows feature. Are you using windows ?

Answer (score 1):

Check your Active Directory settings by following this article guide

https://support.apple.com/guide/directory-utility/welcome/mac

Type

> Directory Utility

in Spotlight to find and start it

[image]